# use asp.net toolbox options in innerhtml statements

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string, innerhtml

I'm trying to insert an ASP.Net button in `InnerHtml` attribute:

```
divAppointmentsToday.InnerHtml += "<tr><td class='appoint-normal-text' height='100px' style='background-color:#f9f9f9; padding-top:20px; padding-left:40px;'>" + reader["actionreporttime"].ToString().Split(' ')[0] + "<br /> " + reader["leadname"] + " <br /> " + reader["organisation"] + "<br />Contact/Mobile :  " + reader["Contactno"] + " / " + reader["Mobile"] + "<br />Product Requested for: " + reader["productrequested"] + "<br /> Action to be taken :<span style='color:#818286'> " + reader["actionreport"].ToString() + "</span><br /> Status :<span style='color:#818286'>" + reader["status1"].ToString() + "</span><br /> Scoring :<span style='color:#818286'>" + reader["status2"].ToString() + "</span><button type=button ID=statusedit>click me</button><br/><a href='Appointments.aspx?idAppointments=" + reader["id"] + "' onClick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want delete?\")'>  <span class='appoint-red-text'>Dismiss</span></a>  /  <a href='Prospect.aspx?id=" + reader["id"] + "#PlanOfActionn'>  <span class='appoint-red-text'>Edit</span></a><br /><br /></td></tr>";
```

This is the ASP.Net button code I want to integrate:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: `Unclear` what you are trying to do!

Comment: wants to add a button in the above innerhtml statement which can do database manupulations.

Comment: runat server cannot be added clientside, you need to instead tie the server side button click to the button so just insert a normal button then look at this post: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-methods-using-JavaScript-and-JQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx, or just hide the button and then unhide it with js